# I need help with a formula please. How to work it out

Tags: logarithms

I need help to understand how to work out this formula.
I am really sorry for the duplicate question, but as i have no reputation points i cant comment on any comments others have made and i cant edit, until it's peer reviewed.

** OD is Optical density, so the OD of S is 0.285 so i am assuming OD(s) = 0.285

This is all the information i have been given, if you down vote please explain why. I dont understand why i need 50 reputation points to even reply to a comment.

OD of S = 0.285
OD of P = 0.22
OD of N = 1.464

a = 2.5
b = -0.70

OD(S) - OD(P)
SNc =  --------------- 
            OD(N) - OD(P)

**Formula:**

Log(Titer) = a + b x Logit(SNc)
or 
Titer = 10^(a + b x Logit(SNc))

What is the value of Titer?

Comment: Here Logit refers to the inverse of the logistic function?  But what base is used? That is, $Logit(p)=log(\frac {p}{1-p})$ but the base is not generally agreed.  Since you use base $10$ for the log, does that mean you want $10$ for the base in the Logit?  Note:  you can edit your question instead of replying to a comment.

Comment: Im not sure, it doesnt say. but its assumed it is 10 rather than e

Comment: Fine, so assume base $10$.  But then you get $$Titer=10^a\,\left(\frac {SNc}{1-SNc}\right)^b$$ Can you finish from here?

Comment: I'll post more details below.  But the base ought to be checked.  Most calculators would default to the base of Logit being $e$...I figure that it should be $10$ here, but it needs to be checked.

Comment: Seems another user had [the same problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467208/can-someone-breakdown-this-formula-to-me-i-cant-understand-it-please-help)

Comment: I will be able to confirm that answer but not for a day or so. does the SNc = 0.05225080385? and then it's 10^2.5(0.05225080385/ (1 - 0.05225080385))^-0.70 ? is that essentially how it works there? Sorry for being a pain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step:
$$SNc = \frac {.285-.22}{1.464-.22}=.0522508...$$

Assuming the base of the $Logit$ function is $10$ then we are to compute:
$$Titer=10^{a+bLogit(SNc)}=10^a\,10^{bLogit(SNc)}$$

But $$Logit(SNc)=Log_{10}\left(\frac {SNc}{1-SNc}\right)=Log_{10}(.055131467)$$
Hence $$Titer=10^{2.5}\,(0.055131467)^{-.7}=2404.475266...$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed exlanation. But why are there two different Logit functions? i was confused earlier why in wiki logit(p) = log( p / 1- p) and on another math website its In(p / 1 - p), with the later using e as the base.

Comment: It is like the log in that people use different bases.  Wolfram Alpha, for example, defaults to base $e$ which, I believe, is the most commonly used base...but, then, it's not that commonly used a function so it's best to verify.